# Running Room Persistence Library queries on coroutines GlobalScope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I read that running routines on GlobalScope is bad practice.

What am doing now is:

```
    class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)


        DataBaseHelper.isDbEmpty(this, object : DataBaseHelper.OnCompleteCheckDB {
            override fun isDBEmpty(result: Boolean) {
                //handle result
            }
        })
    }
}
```

DatabseHelper:

```
class DataBaseHelper() {

companion object {
    fun isDbEmpty(context: Context, param: OnCompleteCheckDB) {

        val db = AppDatabase(context)
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val count = db.movieDao().countElements() <= 0
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                param.isDBEmpty(count)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

It works, but is it bad practice? What should I change if I wish to run it on the ActivityScope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'is [lifecycleScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) extension provided in `lifecycle-runtime-ktx` library, see [Use Kotlin coroutines with Architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines). Just add the library to your app's `build.gradle`

```
...
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0"
}
```

There's also [viewModelScope](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) available, if you're using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) library. At first glance such a logic should be moved into a view model, so the query result will be retained during configuration changes. But let's use `lifecycleScope` since the question is about activity scope.

I've also replaced the callback by a `suspend` function. Coroutines are a great replacement for callbacks, so it's better to use coroutines when it's possible.

And one more thing, creating of a new `AppDatabase` instance multiple times doesn't look like a good idea. It's better to create it once and reuse it throughout your app. You can use Dependency Injection for that purpose, see [Manage dependencies between components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#manage-dependencies).

```kotlin
class DataBaseHelper() {
    companion object {
        suspend fun isDbEmpty(context: Context, param: OnCompleteCheckDB) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val db = AppDatabase(context)
            db.movieDao().countElements() <= 0
        }
    }
}

class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            const dbIsEmpty = DataBaseHelper.isDbEmpty(this)
            //handle result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how I initiate the lifecycleScope?

Comment: @Dim You shouldn't initialize it, just add the library to `build.gradle` and `lifecycleScope` will be available. I updated the answer, hope it helps!

Comment: @Dim I've also updated the answer mentioning `viewModelScope` which is used in combination with ViewModel. Just to be sure you're aware about it.